# joystick is not working after canvas changed to world space

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, joystick

My joystick worked alright until I changed the canvas to world space because I just wanted glowing effect before that it worked pretty well, its just avoiding middle and moving only by sides I downloaded it from unity assets for free and don't know anything about it so I'm asking for help. I also tried different assets but they also were like that.

thanks Seit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find this line in Joystick.cs and comment it out.

```
if (canvas.renderMode == RenderMode.ScreenSpaceCamera)
```